# In Django is it possible to obfuscate or hide client IP from logging on certain pages?

Tags: django

We have a need to allow a user of our internal Django site to send an anonymous email via a contact form to an internal email box. I have all of the framework in place and the messages arrive and are not obviously traceable. However, the Django logs do record the IP address along with a timestamp of all requests.

I am curious if it would be possible to some how hide or perhaps proxy the client IP when the form is submitted to help protect their anonymity?

I have found many articles on how to get the client IP but my searches have not hit upon anything that does the reverse.

I could perhaps alter the Django Logging format to exclude the client IP but it would be good to leave it on for the rest of the site for debugging etc.

thank you in advance.

Comment: What log are you talking about? Server/Django logs should only be viewable by support engineers with suitable privileges anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right. However, this is an internal system meant to provide employees with the confidence that the 'comment' they are submitting via the form is done so with as much anonymity as possible. The support engineers are also employees and the most capable when it comes to backtracking where the 'comment' may have come from as it may be from a colleague. I know that there are other ways for the 'comment' to be traced after it has landed as these same engineers may also be mail admins. But at least that platform has auditing attached. Just trying to reduce visibility.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean "What log are you talking about?" as a separate clarification. Reading it again it looks a little rude, I admit...

Comment: Have you attempted to change `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` within the view that accepts the anonymous comment? Also, another thing you could do for less traceability is pool all comments and only mail them forward eg. every midnight

Comment: No offence take,. No I hadn't. I will do my home work on that. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hi, I have just realised that the log I am refereeing to is, in my case the Apache Access log file and therefore not really part of the Django ecosystem. My apologies. In this case I may need to some how trigger conditional logging on the Apache side. But I suspect I won't be able to obfuscate all appearances of the client IP dependant on what page they were on. Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was to modify the Apache CustomLog entry to exclude specific content from being logged in the Access log based on the URI. I made an entry similar to the following in my vhost config file based on numerous examples and the Apache Logging documentation.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/staff/contact" dontlog
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!dontlog
```